# How to do a horizontal flip animation without setting views to nil?

Tags: ios, uiview, uianimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I am doing the "standard" flip between a map and a list view inside a `UIViewController` with navbar on top, there is a button there that toggles between map showing and list.
I am performing the transition with this method:

```
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.tableView
                        toView:self.mapView
                      duration:1
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion:nil];
```

But after it's done the "from-view" is nil, and after one more toggle, both views are nil. Is there another way to flip between views and keeping both around? Then i don't have to populate and init them again when showing. Kind of bad to do that to a map with alot of pins every time the user flips.

Comment: Show full code on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:):

> **fromView**
>
> The starting view for the transition. By default, this view
> is removed from its superview as part of the transition.
>
> **toView**
>
> The ending view for the transition. By default, this view is added to the
> superview of fromView as part of the transition.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method provides a simple way to transition from the
> view in the fromView parameter to the view in the toView parameter. By
> default, the view in fromView is replaced in the view hierarchy by the
> view in toView. *If both views are already part of your view hierarchy,
> you can include the UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
> option in the options parameter to simply hide or show them*.

So if you don't have both views already as part of your view hierarchy, why not add them beforehand? You could insert `mapview` as a subview below `tableView` (so it doesn't get shown at first) and then call the transition using `UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews` along `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft` as options.